# Django Form ImageField checkbox clear edit

Tags: django, checkbox, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django form and I want to modify the automatic checkbox that comes out in an ImageField field.

The problem is the following:

[image]

The box to clean the saved image appears on a higher line and what I want it to appear next to the word *Clear*.

Does anyone know how to modify this?

Comment: Well I think we need some code, forms, widget if you have custom, html. Maybe model too.

Comment: The model is: logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos', blank=True, null=True).

Comment: still need forms and html. You must have changed something to have this clear with checkbox option. Put that in your question (edit it).

Comment: In the form and in html I do not put anything of that box, for what I have seen, it puts by default the model of django ImageField. That's why I do not know how to edit it so that it appears next to Clear.

Comment: And the html is created with bootstrap

Comment: yes, for me is more a css problem than a problem from django. you should check that